# SIGSEV error (gdb)

Tags: gdb, line, segmentation-fault

I currently am running a c++ file which compiles but crashes when it runs.

I open the debugger and get the following line when I run the program:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0xff0ab210 in strcat () from /lib/libc.so.1

I have no idea what that line means.

Can you explain?

Edit:

I have gotten responses telling me about how I used strcat in the program.
All I have used it for is to be used in par with the atoi method in order to convert a string to hex number.

Edit2:
I have seen something on the code that uses the strcat library, it's the .append function. Would that be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That's a segmentation fault.  Usually it means you're trying to access memory that hasn't been allocated.  Since you're using `strcat` I'm guessing that the destination string hasn't been allocated or not enough memory has been allocated.

Comment: Can you post the line that has the strcat function call?

Comment: I just used it for the atoi method I needed for some methods in the program. Do I make them pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If the seg fault comes from strcat, then it is likely one of the following happened:

1. Your source is a non-null terminated C string (malformed string).
2. The amount of memory allocated in the destination string is not enough to store both the source and the destination + 1 (the null at the end).

Check to see if both cases are covered and hopefully you won't see the SIGSEGV again.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by either case? @Neil